# why is mkdir trying (and rightfully failing) to create the existing root directories?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a step in my jenkins-pipeline script that is supposed to create a directory. The relevant portion looks like this:

```
steps.println 'target file path: ' + folder.toString()
    steps.println 'who am i?: ' + "whoami".execute().text

    def sout = new StringBuilder()
    def serr = new StringBuilder()
    def cmd = ('mkdir -v -p ' + folder.toString())
    steps.println 'cmd = ' + cmd
    def proc = cmd.execute()
    proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
    proc.waitForOrKill(1000)

    if (proc.exitValue() == 0){
        steps.println 'Success: ' + sout
    }
    else {
        steps.println 'ERROR: ' + serr
        throw new Exception('Could not create directory "' + folder.toString() +'"')
    }
```

However, when the code executes, I get the following output:

```
Destination Path = 
/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/atlassianPublishTest_master-6R2ESEJZC6HJUUVOOHAQIN7KEMQAPLOBYDS3KQUR5VE6R5RBIUXA/files/docs/Storfirst Release Notes.pdf
[Pipeline] echo
target file name: Storfirst Release Notes.pdf
[Pipeline] echo
target file path: 
/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/atlassianPublishTest_master-6R2ESEJZC6HJUUVOOHAQIN7KEMQAPLOBYDS3KQUR5VE6R5RBIUXA/files/docs
[Pipeline] echo
who am i?: jenkins

[Pipeline] echo
cmd = mkdir -v -p 
/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/atlassianPublishTest_master-6R2ESEJZC6HJUUVOOHAQIN7KEMQAPLOBYDS3KQUR5VE6R5RBIUXA/files/docs
[Pipeline] echo
ERROR: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/jenkins’: Permission denied
```

I've verified that the permissions are correct for all the folders (home is owned by root, the rest are owned by jenkins and have permissions for everything except global write). Only the bottom two folders do not exist, the rest exist and are properly permissioned.

When I execute the command on the jenkins node by hand, it works as expected, but as you can see, even though this is running as the owner of the folder, it looks like it is trying to create the root folder (/home/jenkins) which it obviously doesn't have permission to create.

Its worth noting the reason I am using the mkdir command instead of groovy's File.mkdirs() is because that silently failed to create the directories also.

Can someone please give me an idea as to what I'm doing wrong here?
Thank you

Comment: Please could you validate permissions and owner of the content this path : **/home/** ...... with `ls -la`  command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipeline groovy script will always get executed on the Jenkins master.

That is: To interact with the file system of a build agent you need to use the provided steps like `dir`, `readFile`, `writeFile`, ...

To execute something on that build agent you have to use either the `bat` or `sh` step depending on the OS it is running.

If you’re using the `String.execute()` method it’ll create a process on the Jenkins master.

Jobs should not interact with the file system or create processes on the master as it could make the whole system unstable.

To ensure this you should always try to use the sandbox as it would not allow such things.

Comment: this was exactly the issue.

Answer (score 0):

*When I execute the command on the jenkins node by hand, it works as expected*

Executing the command logged in as ‘jenkins’ user ?

I don't think its trying its trying to create the root folder, I think it’s merely saying it doesn’t have access to create anything within root folder. Ideally jenkins user should have access to its root folder /home/jenkins and looks like permissions are incorrect here ?

Did a quick test to create a folder under jenkins root directory logged in as a different user and I get the below error as expected. The jenkins root folder already exists and it's getting a permission denied to create anything within this folder as expected

```
mkdir -v -p /home/jenkins/hello/newfolder
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/jenkins’: Permission denied
```

Logged in as jenkins user and ran the command

```
mkdir -v -p /home/jenkins/hello/newfolder
mkdir: created directory ‘/home/jenkins/hello’
mkdir: created directory ‘/home/jenkins/hello/newfolder’
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is correct - you need to use the methods Joerg specified because they work with files in your build's workspace.

Moreover, if you use shell or batch scripting which is always workspace relative and much less of a hassle and safer than coding your own process execution.